# How to show most sold part numbers

Tags: excel

I have large list of items sold and would like to be able to generate a report that shows the most sold items along with how many of each item has been sold.

I'm looking for something along the lines of =countif() but as there are so many unique part numbers I'm not sure how to do this.

To add to the confusion I'm making it so this report automatically generates by dumping the right info into certain worksheets and then running a macro written in vba.

Not asking for a step-by-step approach but maybe someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

edit to show how data is organized:

```
PO#   SO#   Line Item   Material#   Description   Order quantity   Net Price   Customer   Created on
```

The same PO# and SO# will occur with multiple line items for each.

Comment: We need to see how your data is organized.

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student, I just added the column headers to show how the data is arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable with Material# for ROWS and Sum of Order quantity for VALUES then filter for Top 10... .